# Make Wix to not uninstall common dll

Tags: wix

I have Wix project in which I need a common used dll library to be installed if it's absent.
If this dll exists I should not overwrite it.
So, when I set DefaultVersion="0.0.0.0" this dll is not overwritten if it exists, its ok. But when I delete app, the dll is beeing removed. How do I prevent removing dll in the  case when it existed before installation?
I don't want to make it permanent because it should be removed if it didn't exist before installation.

```
<Component Id="myLib.dll" Permanent="no"  Directory="Shared_Dir">
            <File Name="myLib.dll" KeyPath="yes" 
                  Source="mySource\myLib.dll"
                  DefaultVersion="0.0.0.0"
                  />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add reference to `WixUtilExtension` and `xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension"` attribute to `Wix` element in your code.
2. Define `<Property Id="Dll_Installed" Value="false"/>` in `Product` element.
3. Add child `<Condition>NOT Dll_Installed</Condition>` to component `myLib.dll`.
4. Add that somewhere in your code:

   ```
    <Fragment>
    <util:FileSearch
              Id="Dll_Installed"
              Variable="Dll_Installed"
              Path="[Shared_Dir]myLib.dll"
              Result="exists"/>
    </Fragment>
   ```

`DefaultVersion` attribute is not necessary.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Solved this with FileSearch. I've worked before with InnoSetup, it's much more easy and it doesn't remove files on uninstall which it didn't install before.

Answer (score 0):

The feature you are describing is reference counting. The Windows Installer reference counts with Components. Components are identified by their GUID.

So the normal way to address this requirement is to put the File in a Component and make sure the GUID of the Component is stable. The WiX Toolset should do exactly that automatically if if you do not specify the Component/@Guid attribute.

So the default behavior should just work for you.

The only other piece of the puzzle is the Windows Installer will install the latest version of a file. If the file version is the same or less the file will not be installed but will be reference counted.

Based on the details in the question it seems like you should be just fine with:

```
<Component Directory="Shared_Dir">
 <File Source="mySource\myLib.dll" />
</Component>
```

One might ask why the Windows Installer use Components to reference count files. We'll, it allows you to group other resources, like registry keys, together and control their install as a unit. Much more important if you are installing COM servers than plain old files.